# how to extend List[Double]

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I want a custom class that functionally extends `List[Double]`, with some added functionality.  My understanding of ***Pimp My Library*** would lead me to construct something like this:

```
implicit class MahThing(list:List[Double]) {
    def mahStuff = ...
}
```

The problem is, now everywhere `MahThing` is imported, all `List[Double]`s have the option to do `mahStuff`.

Same with:

```
class MahThing(list:List[Double]) {
    def mahStuff ...
}
implicit def toThing(list:List[Double]) = new MahThing(list)
```

Now, `list.toThing` produces `MahThing`, but `MahThing` can't do `List`y stuff.  Painstakingly defining `List` operations in `MahThing` as `list.operation` is painstaking.  For some reason, working with instances of `MahThing`, it's making me e.g. declare variable types during `map` operations.

What I really need is the exact functionality of extending `List[Double]`.  Things that are supposed to be `MahThing` get to do `mahStuff`, and no one else does.  Plus `MahThing` acts just like a `List` in every other respect.

Comment: You could add another implicit conversion - from `MahThing` into `List[Double]`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Is the `list` an implementation detail of a `MahThing`? Do you intend `list` to be mutable such that doing `mahThing.list.someMutatingListOperation(...)` is not viable?

Comment: @BrianKent, I want to do `mahStuff`!  Mostly make guarantees concerning the list... assert properties... whatnot.  To *extend* that statement, `MahThing` *is* a `List`, just one that contains additional functionality.

Comment: @Shadowlands can you write that up as an answer and show that it does what I want?  As stated, I'm running into problems in that anywhere that I import `implicit class MahThing` gives `mahStuff` to all `List`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using implicit conversion is the right way to extend a List[T] (T being Double in your case) functionality (being List[T] final it cannot be extended) and as you saw

> everywhere MahThing is imported, all List[Double]s have the option to
>   do mahStuff.

But, if I got it right, you don't want all List[Double]s to be like that so my suggestion is to create a MahDouble class that will accept a Double as parameter and implicitly convert both ways to Double

```
object MahDouble {
   implicit def toMah(d: Double): MahDouble = new MahDouble(d)
   implicit def backToDouble(m: MahDouble): Double = m.d
}

case class MahDouble(d: Double)
```

then you can use that MahDouble as type for your MahThing List and implicitly convert it from List[MahDouble].

```
object MahThing {
   implicit def toThing(list:List[MahDouble]): MahThing = new MahThing(list)
}

case class MahThing(list:List[MahDouble]) {
   def mahStuff ...
}
```

For any aspect MahDouble will act and be a Double, but only Lists made of MahDouble elements will gain the mahStuff method

```
val mahDoubleList: List[MahDouble] = List(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```

Regards,
Alessandro.

Comment: `MahDouble` could be a value class: `case class MahDouble(d: Double) extends AnyVal`. I wouldn't recommend implicit conversion between `Double` and `mahDouble` - it's too unpredictable (see JavaConvertions vs JavaConverters topics for argumentation). Best way is to add clear method implicitly:  `val mahDoubleList = List(2.0.mah, 3.0.mah, 4.0.mah, 5.0.mah)`, you can get rid of explicit type here, btw.

Comment: @dk14 got it, nice to known that I can do it like this. Thanks :)

Comment: @AlessandroG. thanks for your insight into this.  Pasting everything you've written, with `def mahStuff = println("sup")` I'm unable to `mahDoubleList.mahStuff` .  Thoughts?

Comment: @WalrustheCat you are welcome. Did you, by any chance, got an error like "value mahStuff is not a member of List[MahDouble]"? If so remember to add import MahThing._ everywhere you need to use MahThing

Comment: @AlessandroG. that must have been it, everything seems to be working correctly.  thanks.

Comment: @AlessandroG. any tips on how to go up another level -- seamlessly go between `Stream[MahThing]` and `Stream[List[MahDouble]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

As @Alessandro G. suggested the best way is to create special type for `MahDouble` - not the whole `List`:

```
case class MahDouble(d: Double) extends AnyVal
```

`extends AnyVal` will give you [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) to avoid overhead.

However, I wouldn't recommend you to have implicit conversion between `MahDouble` and `Double` as it's too unpredictable and extremely hard to understand what's going on, see [this article](http://googlyadventures.blogspot.com/2015/06/today-i-learned-javaconverters-vs.html).

But you can still add nice constructor for your special doubles:

```
 implicit class RichDouble(d: Double){
    def mah = MahDouble(d)
 }
```

And here is your type class for lists:

```
 implicit class RichMaxDoubleList(l: List[MahDouble]){
    def mahStuff = "done"
 }
```

So now you can work with it:

```
 scala> val l = List(1.0 mah, 2.0 mah)
 l: List[MahDouble] = List(MahDouble(1.0), MahDouble(2.0))

 scala> l.mahStuff
 res7: String = done
```

You can convert regular list to list of mah's and back as well:

```
scala> List(1.0, 2.0).map(_.mah)
res8: List[MahDouble] = List(MahDouble(1.0), MahDouble(2.0))

scala> res8.map(_.d)
res9: List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your insight into this, but it's not functionally extending List[Double].  This won't work, given the above code:  `List(1.0) map {_.mah} map {_+1}`

Comment: @MahDouble could be a functor if you need to mutate it - just add map operation (based on copy method), or just use 'map { _.d + 1} map {_.mah}'.  Other solutions than wrappers or [Scalaz phantom types](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.htm)  are usually unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I see your implicit conversions working. First, the implicit class:

```
implicit class MahThing(val list: List[Double]) {
   def mahStuff = {
     // ...do your checks
     this // to ensure we get the object back so I can chain list-like functions off it to prove it has been converted back.
   }
}
```

and the reverse implicit def to convert back to a list:

```
implicit def thing2list(thing: MahThing): List[Double] = thing.list
```

Applied to a list of double:

```
scala> dbs.mahStuff
res1: MahThing = MahThing@35e06c5d

scala> dbs.mahStuff.tail
res2: List[Double] = List(0.45)
```

The call to tail shows that the MahStuff instance converts back to a list readily.

Now try with a list of strings:

```
scala> val strs = "foo" :: "bar" :: Nil
strs: List[String] = List(foo, bar)

scala> strs.mahStuff
<console>:13: error: value mahStuff is not a member of List[String]
              strs.mahStuff
                   ^
```

Showing that other list types are not converted.

Comment: Cool, but all `List[Double]`s are converted?

Comment: Yes, so long as - for that list - the implicit conversion is [in scope](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html)